# Rename all columns of dataframe in dplyr without using rename()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to rename my variables in a tidy way but I don't like the rename options.  Normally I would use this:

```
df <- structure(list(hv001 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), hv002 = 1:6, hv003 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L), hv008 = c(1386L, 
1386L, 1386L, 1386L, 1386L, 1386L), hv009 = c(6L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 
4L, 6L), hv025 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("rural", 
"urban"), class = "factor"), hv106_01 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 5L, 
NA, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("don't know", "higher", "no education, preschool", 
"primary", "secondary"), class = "factor"), hv115_01 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("divorced", "married", "never married", 
"widowed"), class = "factor"), ha1_01 = c(NA, NA, 22L, 42L, 25L, 
37L), ha2_01 = c(NA, NA, 494L, 501L, 557L, 800L), ha3_01 = c(NA, 
NA, 1555L, 1498L, 1562L, 1536L), ha53_01 = c(NA, NA, 111L, 144L, 
127L, 131L), ha54_01 = structure(c(NA, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no/don't know", 
"yes"), class = "factor"), ha57_01 = structure(c(NA, NA, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("mild", "moderate", "not anemic", "severe"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

colnames(df) <- c("cluster", "household_number", "respondent_line_number", "date", "num_household_members", location", "education", "marital_status", "age", "weight", "height", 
"hemoglobin", "pregnancy_status", "anemia")
```

I know I can do it this way:

```
df <- df %>% rename(cluster = hv001, household_number = hv002, etc)
```

But it's actually less tidy/efficient with having to type out the old variable names. Is there a way to combine the old method or is there a more efficient method to rename all your columns?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are replacing all the names and you have the new names in the right order, you can do `df %>% setNames(new_names)`. This may be more efficient in terms of typing, but it is definitely more dangerous as it assumes the new names are already in the order that corresponds to the old names.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @GregorThomas!

Comment: you could look into `set_names` also

Comment: @Onyambu I actually found that worked better but they're both great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to rename column by column. You can use set_names, which is equivalent to setNames. Then it is

```
df <- df %>% 
     set_names(nm = c("cluster", "household_number", "respondent_line_number", "date", "num_household_members", location", "education", "marital_status", "age", "weight", "height", 
"hemoglobin", "pregnancy_status", "anemia"))
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I did, based on what @Onyambu said in the comment.  But, since you formalized it, I'll mark it.  Thanks!